# Bloqueio de Espaço com REGEX

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Meu código para bloqueio de caracteres esta assim:

```
 $('#rg').on('keypress', function() {
      var regex = new RegExp("^[ 0-9]+$");
      var _this = this;
      // Curta pausa para esperar colar para completar
      setTimeout( function(){
          var texto = $(_this).val();
          if(!regex.test(texto))
          {
              $(_this).val(texto.substring(0, (texto.length-1)))
          }
      }, 100);
  });

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='rg'/>
```

Como faço o bloqueio do ESPAÇO .

Exemplo Incorreto

> 116 416

Deveria ficar

> 116416

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O teu REGEX está quase certo, como você quer apenas digitos, basta remover o espaço do REGEX que irá funcionar.

```
new RegExp("^[0-9]*$")
```

Veja o exemplo funcionando:

```js
$('#rg').on('keypress', function() {
  var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]*$");
  var _this = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    var texto = $(_this).val();
    if (!regex.test(texto)) {
      $(_this).val(texto.substring(0, (texto.length - 1)))
    }
  }, 100);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='rg' />
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é o espaço do seu regex. deveria ser assim : `RegExp("^[0-9]+$")`.

**Exemplo:**

```js
 $('#rg').on('keypress', function() {
   var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]+$");
   var _this = this;
   // Curta pausa para esperar colar para completar
   setTimeout(function() {
     var texto = $(_this).val();
     if (!regex.test(texto)) {
       $(_this).val(texto.substring(0, (texto.length - 1)))
     }
   }, 100);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="rg">
```